# How do I set up methods on mocks to return null by default?

Tags: c#, autofixture, automoq

I am using AutoFixture with AutoMoq to mock my dependencies in a unit test like this

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyService
{
   MyObject GetMyObject();
}

public class Tests
{
   [Fact]
   public void MyTest()
   {
      var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
      var myService = fixture.Create<Mock<IMyService>>();

      // I want myObject to be null, but I'm getting a Mock<MyObject> instead
      var myObject = myService.Object.GetMyObject();    ​
   ​}
}
```

I want the line `var myObject = myService.Object.GetMyObject();` to return `null`, but instead it returns a `Mock<MyObject>` value.  I known I can do `myService.Setup(e => e.GetMyObject()).Returns((MyObject)null);` to explicitly tell it to return null, but I have a number of methods like that being called throughout my tests and I want them to return null by default, without me having to explicitly call `Setup` on them.

Is there a way to set up the fixture to have all methods on the mock return `null` by default?

Comment: `.Customize<MyObject>(x => x.FromFactory(() => null)` ?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried your suggestion, but I still get the same behavior.  I think the problem is the `AutoMoqCustomization`, but I can't remove that because I need it to create the mocks that I don't want to be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion from the comments was close. The part that was missing is setting the `CofnigureMembers` property on `AutoMoqCustomization` to `true` so that AutoFixture can resolve the instances of the members.

```cs
[Fact]
public void MyTest()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization
    {
        ConfigureMembers = true,
    });
    fixture.Inject<MyObject>(null));
    var myService = fixture.Create<Mock<IMyService>>();

    var myObject = myService.Object.GetMyObject();
    
    Assert.Null(myObject);
}
```